# Debug Assertion Failed! Weird issue

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, delete-operator

[DebugAssertionFailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmvQd.png)

[AccessViolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjg9.png)

The two pictures above show the error Im having. The order they are in are the order they appear.
When the first one shows up, I hit retry, then the second one comes up, and I hit continue, then it repeats, when I finally break, a tab shows up titled "msvcr120d.i386.pdb not loaded". When the program breaks it points me to the following line the the DynamicQueue.h code: "delete temp;"

All of dynamicqueue.h and most of BinaryTree.h, are copied straight from the book, so I don't know what's causing the issue (mainly because I have no clue what the issue is). The parts of BinaryTree.h that involve converting to Dynamic Queue were written by me.

The following is my code:

DynamicQueue.h

```
#ifndef DYNAMICQUEUE_H
#define DYNAMICQUEUE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Dynamic Queue Template
template <class T>
class DynamicQueue{
private:
    struct QueueNode{
        T value;
        QueueNode* next;
    };

    QueueNode* front;
    QueueNode* rear;
    int numItems;

public:
    //Constructor
    DynamicQueue();

    //Destructor
    ~DynamicQueue();

    //Queue Operations
    void enqueue(T);
    void dequeue(T &);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    void clear();
};


//Constructor
template <class T>
DynamicQueue<T>::DynamicQueue(){
    front = nullptr;
    rear = nullptr;
    numItems = 0;
}



//Destructor
template <class T>
DynamicQueue<T>::~DynamicQueue(){
    clear();
}



//enqueue
template <class T>
void DynamicQueue<T>::enqueue(T item){
    QueueNode* newNode = nullptr;

    newNode = new QueueNode;
    newNode->value = item;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if (isEmpty()){
        front = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
    }
    else{
        rear->next = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
    }

    numItems++;
}



//Dequeue
template <class T>
void DynamicQueue<T>::dequeue(T &item){
    QueueNode* temp = nullptr;

    if (isEmpty())
        cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
    else{
        item = front->value;
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp; //When the program breaks, it points me here....

        numItems--;
    }
}



//isEmpty
template <class T>
bool DynamicQueue<T>::isEmpty() const{
    return !numItems > 0;
}




//clear
template <class T>
void DynamicQueue<T>::clear(){
    T value;
    while (!isEmpty())
        dequeue(value);
}


#endif
```

BinaryTree.h

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "DynamicQueue.h"

using namespace std;

//BinaryTree Template
template <class T>
class BinaryTree{
private:
    struct TreeNode{
        T value; // TThe value in the node
        TreeNode* left; //Pointer to the left child node
        TreeNode* right; //Pointer to the right child node
    };

    TreeNode* root; //Pointer to the root node

    //Private methods
    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    void destroySubtree(TreeNode *&);
    void deleteNode(T, TreeNode *&);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
    void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPreOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPostOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void loadInQueue(DynamicQueue<T>, TreeNode *);


public:
    //Constructor
    BinaryTree(){
        root = nullptr;
    }

    //Destructor
    ~BinaryTree(){
        destroySubtree(root);
    }

    //Binary Tree Operations
    void insertNode(T);
    bool searchNode(T);
    void remove(T);

    void displayInOrder() const{
        displayInOrder(root);
    }

    void displayPreOrder() const{
        displayPreOrder(root);
    }

    void diplayPostOrder() const{
        displayPostOrder(root);
    }

    void convertToQueue(DynamicQueue<T> &);
};


//Insert Method
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insert(TreeNode* &nodePtr, TreeNode* &newNode){
if (nodePtr == nullptr)
nodePtr = newNode; //Insert the node
else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
    insert(nodePtr->left, newNode); //Search the left branch
else
insert(nodePtr->right, newNode); //Search the right branch
}


//insertNode
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insertNode(T item){
    TreeNode* newNode = nullptr;

    //Create a new Node and store val in it
    newNode = new TreeNode;
    newNode->value = item;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = nullptr;

    //Insert the node
    insert(root, newNode);
}


//DestorySubTree
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::destroySubtree(TreeNode* &nodePtr){
    if (nodePtr){
        if (nodePtr->left)
            destroySubtree(nodePtr->left);
        if (nodePtr->right)
            destroySubtree(nodePtr->right);

        delete nodePtr;
    }
}



//searchNode
template <class T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::searchNode(T item){
    TreeNode* nodePtr = root;

    while (nodePtr){
        if (nodePtr->value == item)
            return true;
        else if (item < nodePtr->value)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
        else
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
    }
    return false;
}



//remove
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::deleteNode(T item, TreeNode* &nodePtr){
    if (item < nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->left);
    else if (item > nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(nodePtr);
}



template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::makeDeletion(TreeNode* &nodePtr){
    TreeNode* tempNodePtr = nullptr;
    if (nodePtr == nullPtr)
        cout << "Cannot delete empty node.\n";
    else if (nodePtr->right == nullptr){
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->left == nullptr){
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    else{
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr->right;
        while (tempNodePtr->left)
            tempNodePtr = tempNodePtr->left;
        tempNodePtr->left = nodePtr->left;
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
}



//displayInOrder
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayInOrder(TreeNode* nodePtr) const{
    if (nodePtr){
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}



//displayPreOrder
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPreOrder(TreeNode* nodePtr) const{
    if (nodePtr){
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayPreOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayPreOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}


//displayPostOrder
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPostOrder(TreeNode* nodePtr) const{
    if (nodePtr){
        displayPostOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayPostOrder(nodePtr->right);
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
    }
}

//ConvertToQueue
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::convertToQueue(DynamicQueue<T> &queue){
    queue.clear();
    loadInQueue(queue, root);
}

//LoadInQUEUE
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::loadInQueue(DynamicQueue<T> queue, TreeNode* nodePtr){
    if (nodePtr){
        loadInQueue(queue, nodePtr->left);
        queue.enqueue(nodePtr->value);
        loadInQueue(queue, nodePtr->right);
    }
}

#endif
```

ConvertBinaryTreeToQueue.cpp

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "DynamicQueue.h"

using namespace std;


void main(){

    BinaryTree<int> tree;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tree.insertNode(i * 5);
    }

    DynamicQueue<int> queue;
    tree.convertToQueue(queue);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()){
        int value;
        queue.dequeue(value);
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    _getch();

}
```

If anyone can help me solve, or at least come to understand the issue, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Note: I come from a Java background, I've had issues before where I'll try to do something that works in Java, but doesnt work in C++, so I wouldn't be surprised if that was again the issue, but I normally get more standardized error messages when thats the case.

Comment: Do not post links to images. Post the text of the error messages. You should also invoke the debugger and report the line causing the issue.

Comment: Well the problem is that its not giving me a line that's causing the issue. The Program compiles, and then when it breaks it doesn't say exactly where.

Comment: Press Retry to debug the application.

Comment: I do, and it says it hits a break point on line 87 in DynamicQueue.h, but there's no breakpoint there, and DynamicQueue.h is straight from the book. Other than that, it doesn't give me an error. If I hit continue after the break point, it just keeps giving me the same two error messages.

Comment: Something has corrupted the heap. It could be caused by this queue, or unrelated code which happens to corrupt its data. The easiest way to avoid these errors is not to use any manual memory management, and use only containers and smart pointers. Also don't assume code from books is good or correct.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused by what's causing the issue. Do you have any specific advice on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Both errors are related to your program trying to access memory that it is not allowed too (any more).

In this function `convertToToQueue` you create a new `DynamicQueue` called `newQueue` that gets destroyed when the scope of that function ends:

```
//ConvertToQueue
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::convertToQueue(DynamicQueue<T> &queue){
    DynamicQueue<T> newQueue;
    loadInQueue(newQueue, root);

    queue = newQueue;
}
```

Assigning `newQueue` to `queue` is not going to do what you might expect. The class `DynamicQueue` lacks a copy-constructor, so the compiler will make one for you to the best of its knowledge. It copies the values of `front`, `rear` and `numItems`.

When `newQueue` goes out of scope, all the `QueueNode` objects in it are deleted (because the destructor of `DynamicQueue` calls `clear();`). At this point, `queue.front` and `queue.end` are pointing to invalid memory.

Instead of creating a new `DynamicQueue` you should pass in the `queue` from the arguments. If you want to make sure `queue` only contains the items from the `BinaryTree` you can call `queue.clear();` before calling `loadInQueue`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The tip was good for bettering the design, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I have update the method, but it appears to be giving me the same problem.

Edit: I've updated the code above with the fix.

Comment: Update: After a little bit more tweaking with this new advice in mind, I've gotten it working. Thank you so much!